# Change GET variable with htaccess on a single page

Tags: .htaccess

I have a single page with one GET parameter: `reference`.

After filling in the form, the url I have at the moment looks like:

`https://www.my-website.com/directory/hw/?referentie=29384`

Now I want it to be changed (only on this particular `tracking` page) to:

`https://www.my-website.com/hw/tracking/29384`

How is this achievable with .htaccess?

---

**My current .htacess file (located in `/directory`) looks like:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^tracking    tracking.php    [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

This redirects the page to .php without having to write .php down.

---

**I tried the following (without success):**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^tracking    tracking.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tracking/(.*)$ tracking.php?reference=$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^tracking/?$ tracking.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} tracking/?\d*\?referentie=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /hw/tracking/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(tracking)/(\d+)$ $1.php?referentie=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Remove and replace everything you have with the above rules. Place it inside server root directory.

Comment: I also noticed that the url is `directory/tracking/?reference=29384` instead of `directory/tracking?reference=29384`. May that cause it being unsuccesful? :)

Comment: @DaanHeskes Can you provide the apache's access logs?

Comment: Also, I'm unsure if I need RewriteBase, as the .htaccess is already hosted in the `/directory/`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me through the chat, I'm very thankful for the attemtps you've made and helping me with the correct solution. You deserve way more credit than I can give you. I can't thank you enough.